# Importing multiple XML to Excel as excel table

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am using below code to import multiple xml files to excel. The code is working fine. The only issue I am facing is, it is not importing to excel as XML table. I would like to import them as table for further processing with this data.

```
Sub XMLtoExcel()
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook
    xCount = 1
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        xWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(xCount, 1)
        xWb.Close False
        xCount = xSWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xSWb.Save
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Can anyone provide me a hint to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by `not importing to excel as excel table`?

Comment: I mean import as XML table.

Comment: you are doing a `.UsedRange.Copy` so whatever data you have in that file will get copied. Can you show using a screenshot what exactly are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub XMLtoExcel()
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long

    Dim myURL As String
    Dim n As Long


    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook

    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        n = n + 1
        If n = 1 Then
            Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        Else
            myURL = xStrPath & "\" & xFile
            ImportToxml myURL, xWb
        End If
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    xSWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Clear
    xWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    xWb.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xSWb.Save
    Exit Sub
End Sub
Sub ImportToxml(myURL As String, Wb As Workbook)

    Dim myMap As XmlMap
    Set myMap = Wb.XmlMaps(1)
        myMap.Import URL:=myURL, Overwrite:=False

End Sub
```

If your workbook have the same xml map,
The code will change like this

```
Sub XMLtoExcel()
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long

    Dim myURL As String
    Dim n As Long


    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook

    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While xFile <> ""
            myURL = xStrPath & "\" & xFile
            ImportToxml myURL, xSWb

        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    xWb.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
End Sub
Sub ImportToxml(myURL As String, Wb As Workbook)

    Dim myMap As XmlMap
    Set myMap = Wb.XmlMaps(1)
        myMap.Import URL:=myURL, Overwrite:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dy.Lee. this code is also importing value as same way as my code. there is a order difference in the data displaying using this method vs when I import as xml table (manually).

Comment: @acr:  sorry, is your xmls  same map?

Comment: @acr: I modify my code.  I think  option overwrite:=fale  make importing multiple xml.

Comment: importoxml myURL, xWb   - sub or function not defined

Comment: Thanks. But it is still not loading as a table. I think I need to look for an alternate solution.

Comment: I think, for getting data as xml type,  you must get data of xlm to your book with  map exist.